# How to resolve java.lang.NoSuchMethodError org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnType

Tags: java, exception, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to run the CountVectorizerDemo program provided here:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/JavaCountVectorizerExample.java

I'm getting the following error and don't know what the problem is.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnType$default$4()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizerParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(CountVectorizer.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer.validateAndTransformSchema(CountVectorizer.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer.transformSchema(CountVectorizer.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer.fit(CountVectorizer.scala:130)
    at com.bah.ossem.spark.topic.CountVectorizerDemo.main(CountVectorizerDemo.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:664)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my cluster was using Spark core 1.4 but my application was using Spark core 1.5.1 and MLlib 1.5.1. I updated my AWS cluster to Spark 1.5.1 and that fixed the problem.